# Accessing the form in the controller - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Question regarding coding the right way with forms in angularJS.

I want to access the form in the controller. How can I achieve it without accessing the form name in the controller like that $scope.formName?

Do it like that tightly coupled the view and the controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Following the example in AngularJS documentation it seems you need to name your form https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the form name to the controller

```
<button type="button" ng-click="validateForm('myForm')">
    Validate
</button>
```

In controller

```
$scope.validateForm = function(formName) {
    var form = $scope[formName];
    form.$valid;
};
```

Comment: But I want the form regardless of view event.

Comment: @einav use ng-init="setForm(myForm)" in that case.